# jquery positioning pop up

Tags: jquery, html, css

when i click the english button the pop up comes up but i can see the full contents of popup only after i scroll down...
is there any way I can see the full contents of pop up with out scrolling down

i am providing my code below
http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/130/

original code

http://www.teslamotors.com/

**there is some problem in js code**

```
    // locale selector actions
    $('#region-picker').click(function(){
        var foot_height = $('#footer').innerHeight();
        var foot_height_css = foot_height-1;
        var select_position = '-=' + (Number(400)+18);
        console.log("hallo"+select_position);
        var $selector = $('#locale-select');
        $('#locale_pop').fadeOut();
        $selector.css({top:foot_height_css});
        $selector.fadeIn(function(){
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).animate({top:select_position}, 1000);
            });
    });
    $('#select-tab').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        closeSelector('slide');
        });
    // don't hide when clicked within the box
    $('#locale-select').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){ 
        if ($('#locale-select').hasClass('open')) {
            closeSelector('disappear');
        }
    });

    $('.locale-link').click(function(){
        var desired_locale = $(this).attr('rel');
        createCookie('desired-locale',desired_locale,360);
        createCookie('buy_flow_locale',desired_locale,360);
        closeSelector('disappear');
    })

    $('#locale_pop a.close').click(function(){
        var show_blip_count = readCookie('show_blip_count');
        if (!show_blip_count) {
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        else if (show_blip_count < 3 ) {
            eraseCookie('show_blip_count');
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        $('#locale_pop').slideUp();
        return false;
    });

function closeSelector(hide_type){
    var foot_height = $('#footer').innerHeight();
    var select_position = '+=' + (Number(400)+20);
    if (hide_type == 'slide') {
        $('#locale-select').animate({top:select_position}, 1000, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $(this).fadeOut()
        });
    }
    else if (hide_type == 'disappear'){
        $('#locale-select').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#locale-select').removeClass('open');
    }
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up is pretty big, so depending on the size of your monitor, it might not fit on the screen all at once.  However, you can get it to come up a bit higher by changing:

```
var select_position = '-=' + (Number(400)+18);
```

to:

```
var select_position = '-=' + (Number(700)+18);
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/131/)

Comment: thanks for your reply i have another question too...when i click the english us the pop up comes up but when i click english us the popup does not go down in the opposite direction can u tell me how to fix it... latest code http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/138/   div class="locale-tab" id="select-tab" style="width: 132px;"> -->
   <!--     <span class="en_US tk-museo-sans">SELECT COUNTRY</span> -->
  <!--    </div> -->

Comment: Hey sorry, I was out of town.  Did you still need help with this?     -- By the way, if I answered your question, can you click the thing that gives me the points?  I need 6 more points before I can comment anywhere.